# How do I measure performance of mongodb client connect in express.js?

Tags: mongodb, express

I'm inclined to call MongoClient.connect on each http request (app.get, app.post etc) rather wrapping each request handler in the connect callback. How can I measure the performance tradeoffs?

Answer (score 1):

just use mongoose.
Mongoose provides a straight-forward, schema-based solution to model your application data. It includes built-in type casting, validation, query building, business logic hooks and more, out of the box.
[read more][1]

you can install it by below command

```
npm install mongoose --save
```

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html